# UIImage is extending beyond its constraints when it receives an image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift2

I have the following layout constrained by multiple `UIStackView` objects:

[image]

When I run the app, I get the layout as intended:

[image]

However, when I load an image from my server, the image expands past it's bounds and covers up the top two labels:

[image]

I've encountered this problem in the past, and I decided to evade it then. This time I want to find out the solution to this problem. I've tried using calls like:

`imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true`
`imageView.clipsToBounds = true`

but there is no effect.

Comment: Did you try `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`?

Comment: Click on your imageView, goto size inspector and check for the last option. Your problem may be arising due "intrinsic size" being as placeholder. If so, change it to "Default(System defined)". Also as Abhinav stated, you could  use "UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill" mode.